# Access point has incredible slow speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I set up 4G LTE network because I live in a village so there is no better solution. I have the router in the attic: `ZTE NETBOX MF-258K`. On the second floor speed of the Internet is good, I am satisfied. Router connection doesn't reach the first floor so I've bought a second router and set it as an access point(have built-in function - just disable DHCP) and this router name: `Archer AX23` - on the first-floor connection is heavy, flies like blood. My questions are:

- Have I bought the wrong device?
- Can I check something else to repair the slow connection?

Device: **Router ZTE MF258 ODU/IDU**
Max speed: **800 Mb/s**
Standard: **802.11a/b/g/n/ac**
Antennas: **2**
Router operating frequency: **2,4GHz / 5 GHz**
Max upload speed: **150 Mb/s**

Wifi status
Band: **2.4Ghz**
Mode: **802.11b/g/n**
Channel: **13**
Lan Status devices: **ArcherAX23 - LAN.DHCP**
———————————————
Second device: **ArcherAX23**
Max. Transfer wifi speed: **1800 Mb/s**
Architecture: **Gigabit Ethernet**
Standard: **802.11a/n/b/g/ac/ax**
Antennas: **4**

Wifi status 2.4GHz
Channel(auto): **7**

Wifi status 5Ghz
Channel(auto): **44**

Gateway **192.168.1.1** <- Main router
Router as access point: **192.168.1.149**

Comment: So everything is wireless?

Comment: the access point is connected by RJ cable to the main router. Both work wireless, also I checked the channels and both have different ones.

Comment: It's possible that some interference by a strong electrical device is causing transmits. Also, if you have used 5 GHz, know that it works much worse than 2.4 GHz for passing through obstructions such as walls or ceilings. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Can you provide some specific details?

Comment: *"Both have different"*: provide the channel numbers so we can make sure they are different *enough*

Comment: @harrymc So should I use everywhere 2.4GHz and turn off 5GHZ

Comment: @Ramhound I added more details

Comment: Try indeed to see if using 2.4GHz improves the reception.

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to the 2.4 GHz network offered by the Archer access point . How are the two access points connected?

Comment: @Ramhound Main Router->Ethernet Cable->Access Point.